# Clone LUKS encrypted SSD to bigger NVMe

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, encryption

I want to clone a (partly) LUKS encrypted SSD to another bigger NVMe. After that I want to create a separate partition out of unused space.

The disk I like to clone contains a dual boot setup with Fedora and Windows 10. So there is also GRUB installed.

What I did so far is booting from a Live USB image (Ubuntu). So the LUKS partitions are still encrypted and not mounted. I also checked that the sector size is 512 bytes for both disks. I used dd to clone the complete disk to the new disk:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=32M status=progress
```

To my understanding the new disk should work exactly like the old one because it's an exact copy. So even the UUIDs of the partitions should be the same. If I now shutdown the Live Boot and unplug the old disk I can get to GRUB and see the boot options but if I select Fedora I don't get the password prompt to decrypt the disk as I would normally see it. Instead I'm running into some dracut timeouts and can only enter an emergency shell.

```
___common_interrupt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
___common_interrupt: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
.
.
.
___common_interrupt: 10.55 No irq handler for vector
[ OK ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[ OK ] Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[ OK ] Reached target Paths.
dracut-iniqueue[548]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
.
.
.
dracut-iniqueue[548]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
dracut-iniqueue[548]: Warning: Could not boot.
Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...
Warning: /dev/fedora_localhost-live/root does not exist
Warning: /dev/fedora_localhost-live/swap does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost-live--root does not exist
Warning: crypto LUKS UUID 487cc016-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also do understand that my GPT table is now somehow broken because the new disk is bigger so I tried to fix it using gparted (again with Ubuntu Live image). During startup of gparted it asked me to fix the table and so I did it. But still I can't decrypt my disk when booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:
In the encrypted system you need to put the new device name into [/etc/crypttab](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Disk_Encryption_User_Guide#Add_the_mapping_information_to_.2Fetc.2Fcrypttab) and rebuild your initial ramdisk image. This can be done from a live system by mounting the encrypted system and chroot-ing into it, or with the emergency shell.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the missing link.