# Clone LUKS encrypted SSD to NVME (slightly different size)

Tags: linux, ssd, clone, nvme, luks

I bought a same sized NVME as my previous SSD to clone it.
I mean I thought they were of the same size. Both are supposed to be 1 TB discs.

I did:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/nvme1n1 bs=64K conv=sync,noerror status=progress
```

`nvme1n1` (whitout p1 or p2, etc).

Now these are the exact sizes in bytes:

| old device | size (old device) |  | size (new device) | new device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sda | 100020**7286272** | > | 100020**4886016** | nvme1n1 |
| sda1 | 1207960064 | = | 1207960064 | nvme1n1p1 |
| sda2 | 99899**8277632** | > | 99899**5877376** | nvme1n1p2 |

The SSD was LUKS encrypted.

Now on my GRUB I get errors of:

- /dev/mapper... has size of xxxxxxxx sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of yyyyyyyyy sectors. Was devize resized?
  One or more devices used as PVs in VG volumegroup have changed sizes.
- **grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1. Check your device map**
- lsblk: /dev/mapper/volumegroup-home: not a block device

I tried edditing `/etc/crypttab` [as stated in this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1644711/clone-luks-encrypted-ssd-to-bigger-nvme#comment2514165_1644724) but I don't understand the answer and the changes I should make.

That answer talks about:

- Changing the device name: The old /etc/crypttab file has a `sdb2_crypt UUID=... none luks, discard` line.

  If I just change that "device name" `sdb2_crypt` to new `nvme1n1p2_crypt` it doesn't work.
- rebuilding initial ramdisk image: I don't know if that is mounting the partitions on a live environment and I did this:

  `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

  Because after that I still got errors of:

  - sector size being smaller, and
  - it doesn't find /dev/sda2 and
  - `/dev/mapper/volumegroup-home: not a block device`.

---

To sum up, I would need more detailed info on the specific steps to clone the disc from SSD to NVME without getting references to sector size being smaller (sinze I didn't change the size) and missing an old `sda` device when now it is an nvmep1. The info there was not enough for me to understand it.

I'm running Debian stable. The quoted question/answer was referred to Fedora systems, and links to Fedora documentation, so I don't know if any difference would apply to my OS.

Comment: Great, incorrectly closed as duplicate… you can appeal on [meta] if you care. Disk sizes use "marketing gigabytes" - how much bytes that is exactly varies by model. Your new drive is about 6.5 MB smaller. Both are slightly over the advertised 1 TB. Repartition the old drive to free up a couple MBs at the end, then clone again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Since I got the question closed and thought I wouldn't have any more help and couldn't solve it, I had to do a clean install on the NVME... now I've been customazing the install there to the point I can't go to the previous disk. I'll still wait a few weeks in case I "miss" somethinig from the old one, to still have it all there to copy. After that, I'll try to clone the other way around (NVME to SSD) and check if it works, so I can have an entire disk backup. Again, thank you very much.